# How to create Model class in Objective C++?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, objective-c++

I want to make Model class in objective c++ which contains Name & Email id.
Like what we do in Swift 3  ex:-

```
import UIKit

class modelDemo: NSObject {

    var name : String = ""
    var emailId : String = ""
}
```

& we are accessing modelDemo like ex:-

```
  let modelVar : [modelDemo] = []
   // after inserting values in Model 
    print("first object is \(modelvar[0].name)")
```

Can we implement same thing in objective c++?

Comment: With Objective-C++ you can choose to create either an Objective-C class or a C++ class. Which one you want to create?

Comment: Objective c++ class with .mm extension

Comment: There is no Obj-C++ class. Obj-C++ is a combination of Obj-C and C++. You can create either an Obj-C class or a C++ class. A C++ class cannot inherit from `NSObject` though.

Comment: Once we create Objective c class then edit file with .m to .mm right navigator will show Objective c++ class.

Comment: What are you looking for a C++ model or an Obj-C model? Both are not same. Obj-C++ model doesn't exist. In a .mm file, you can use C++ and Obj-C simultaenously

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ModelDemo: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* emailId;
@end

@implementation ModelDemo
@end
```

...

```
ModelDemo* model = [ModelDemo new];
model.name = @"Hello"
NSArray<ModelDemo*> *array = @[model];
NSLog(@"Name: %@",array[0].name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is very unclear, but I think I may have an idea. Are you asking whether it is possible to **create a C++ class that is a subclass of an ObjC class**?

Swift is not C++, even though a Swift class in source code looks very similar to a C++ class, but it is more similar to an ObjC class internally. That's why you can make a Swift class that is a subclass of an ObjC class.

That won't work with C++ though. All you can do with ObjC++ is create an ObjC class that contains a C++ class as one of its instance variables, or a C++ class that contains an ObjC class. If you do that, you can write code that reacts to a message and forwards it to the C++ class etc., but there is no way to subclass an ObjC class using C++ or the other way round.

Also, you should read up on the difference between files and classes. A file can contain 0 or more classes. An ObjC file can contain ObjC classes, a C++ file can contain C++ classes. An ObjC++ file can contain ObjC classes and/or C++ classes.

You have to pick what you need. What are you using this for, and why? There is no such thing as an ObjC++ class. Why do you want to use ObjC++? Why not just go with ObjC or C++ alone? Help us understand the reason behind that need in your concrete case, and we can give you useful answers.